# How can i validate the N-th element of an array with N elements with vuelidate

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuelidate

I have an array with N elements (size is changing) and i am using vuelidate for the validation. I don't found an example where my validation method can see the iterator/index of selected array element. For example i have 3 textfields inside an array. All the elements are requiered. If i let the 1st element empty, ALL the 3 textfields gonna display the same error ("Textfield is required"). Is there a solution ??? Thank you very much for each answer

Answer (score 1):

Fairly simple - use `every` and `forEach`:

```
if (!arrayOfTextFields.every(t => t.value != "" && t.value != "Textfield is required")) {
    arrayOfTextFields.forEach(t => t.value = "Textfield is required");
}
```